# TF30063: You are not authorized to access Collection. Nuget and Tfs conflicting

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, version-control, nuget

**Latest Comment**

I believe my problem occurs when using Nuget, however, if you are reading because of the TF30063 error. Have a look at the answer I provided and accepted.

**Original Post**

I am getting this error message when I try to check out. This happens randomly and can occur even if minutes ago the same instance of visual studio allowed me to check something else out for edit.
[image]

The current workaround is to reopen VS2010.

Using W7x64, vs2010 ultimate with TF2010 and sql2008 on my local dev machine. I am not part of a domain. I am the administrator of this computer.

**Additional 2011-08-09**

When the problem occurrs, I "close solution" under file. And then reopen the solution. I then get a uid/pwd box. I put my admin uid/pwd into it and then get a further error message. Again, closing vs2010 and reopening solves the issue.

[image]
[image]

**Additional: 2011-08-30**

I believe this has to do with nuget. I have provided an answer and so far after many months I have not had a TFS error. Where I should have had an error given the types of operations I have been performing which were identical to the scenarios making it fail.

Comment: Sometimes I got sameproblem. I assume it has got to do with some kind of connection loss. But I'm also interessted in any hint on that topic

Comment: Out of curiosity have you got your TFS credentials stored in the Windows Credential Manager?  Just trying to understand the problem in a little more detail.

Answer (score 88, accepted):

I noticed that the problem occurred mostly after i installed a nuget package. After adding a nuget package i found that I could not check out. Restarting Visual Studio helped.

Based on this discussion:

http://nuget.codeplex.com/discussions/254328

i used this solution which appears to be working:
(I have copied the solution here if ever the webpage disappears)

```
Control Panel / Internet Options / Security Tab
Select "Local Intranet"
Click Sites button
Click Advanced Button
Add your TFS server http address to the list. e.g. http://tfs
Restart Visual Studio
```

Source: http://blog.rthand.com/post/2011/08/26/Fixing-combination-of-NuGet-and-Team-Foundation-in-workgroup-configuration-401-Unauthorized.aspx (Go straight down to `The Solution` half way down).

Don't let the Internet Options part fool you. I do not use Internet Explorer and this solved my issue.

Comment: Wow what a random ridiculous bug I never would have solved. Thank goodness for stackoverflow haha.

Comment: Thanks ! This problem bugged me since > 12 months (long before i installed nuget) but with a tfs server on the internet.

Comment: We've been putting up with this for way too long! The second blog post worked for me.

Comment: Thank you for sharing this - I am amazed that Microsoft did not fix this bug - it has been there for quite for a while. +1

Comment: Worked for me as well. You saved my time.

Comment: Good grief! Thank you! My W7 desktop worked fine but my W8 laptop refused with that misleading authentication error until I messed with Internet Settings as you suggested. How silly.

Comment: did it for me also. although i am wondering now whether if i was logged into visual studio online via the browser if it would have done it. anyway, thanks for that.

Comment: Bizarre!  I had no problems until Windows required me to change my password.  I could download the JSON file via a browser, but VS was giving the 401 error.  This fixed it... Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I found this issue and the accepted solution didn't work for me.  For me the problem occurred when trying to add a NuGet package to my project (through either the console or the GUI) and it would show the login prompt but not accept my user/password.  It would try around 4 times and then fail and roll back the installation.

It turns out for me the issue was that I had Fiddler open and as soon as I closed it (to undo the proxy settings) I was then able to install the package without any issue.  I didn't even have to restart Visual Studio to get it working.

Just thought I'd share this for the next person who comes across this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I want to add a solution for people who are using VisualStudio online.   My problem was that I was logged into VS2013 with the wrong Microsoft Account.

Comment: Thanks for this for VisualStudio online.  After reading this, I checked my details in VS and it had the yellow [!].  A login + restart of VS and all's good (at least as far as this error goes...)

Answer (score 1):

I would like to point that the accepted solution didn't work for me - probably it is for IE users.

My fix was to "clear the package cache"

1. Open VS
2. Go to Tools-> Options
3. Open "NuGet Package Manager" and select General
4. Click in the button: "clear the package cache"

Answer (score 0):

When I had this problem I checked Event Viewer on my TFS machine and it showed a bunch of insufficient permissions Windows Sharepoint Service errors. I ended up just disabling the Sharepoint aspects of TFS since I wasn't using them anyways.

Comment: thank you for adding things to investigate. The problem is occurring now and I cannot see any related Event viewer events. I do not have sharepoint services too.

Answer (score -1):

Got the error TF30063: You are not authorized to access Collection  when comparing or merging the solutions in tfs 2012.
I found that enabling and disabling the windows authentication in IIS did randomly fix the error but found the disk space issue, 
Once i cleared it, and enabled the windows authentication for TFS in IIS, it was a fix for me.!
-Pasha

Answer (score -2):

This answer got me far enough to solve:

> Control Panel / Internet Options / Security Tab Select "Local
>   Intranet" Click Sites button Click Advanced Button Add your TFS server
>   http address to the list. e.g. http://tfs Restart Visual Studio

On our internal network, for some reason, our computers don't always recognize other computers as being part of the domain - resulting in connections being sporadic/intermittent. My user had a restricted list set by domain policy, so I couldn't edit it. However, I could change the connection from just the computer name to the computer's fully qualified domain name and that appears to have solved the problem.

Comment: pls explain how your answer is different to the accepted answer.