# NuGet causing TFS authorization problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, nuget

I am correctly authorised with TFS, and I can check in changes etc. But when I try to get a package from Nuget I get the following error, and after that I get authorisation problems form every operation until I restart VS. What could be causing the issue?

[image: TF330063:You are not authorized to access]

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672516/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-collection-nuget-and-tfs-conflicting

Answer (score 7):

Try this out http://blog.rthand.com/post/2011/08/26/Fixing-combination-of-NuGet-and-Team-Foundation-in-workgroup-configuration-401-Unauthorized.aspx.