# Error TF30063: You are not authorized to access ... \DefaultCollection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, tfs, azure-devops

I'm using [TFS Preview](https://tfspreview.com/) (Team Foundation Service) with one of my projects with Visual Studio 2012. I'm also using an on-premises TFS server with most of my projects. When I use my on-premises TFS after using TFS preview and go back to using TFS preview, I get this error:

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access MyProject\DefaultCollection.

If I go to *Team* → *Disconnect TFS* and then connect to TFS preview again, I'm able to see a "Loading identifiers" loading screen coming up, but in the end I don't get to enter my credentials to TFS preview (my Microsoft account) and as a result, the TF30063 error still occurs.

I suspect this has something to do with my Microsoft account (i.e. Live ID). I'm logged in to Windows with the same Microsoft account that I use at TFS preview. I have logged in to other sites (Windows Development Center, MSDN, etc.) with other Microsoft accounts, but I verified that if I log out of these services and re-login with the correct Microsoft account, I still get the TF30063 error when I try to log in to TFS preview from Visual Studio.

Comment: maybe this will help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6672516/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-collection-nuget-and-tfs-conflicting

Comment: Sadly, no. This also happens with a fresh install and seems to have more to do with multiple Microsoft Accounts than TFS-related authentication. The TFS Preview login apparently uses Internet Explorer and thus might conflict with other MS Accounts you are using.

I came accross this [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/TFService/thread/adbb8bcf-16cc-4476-8154-3b5358543d02) and fully clearing the IE cache seems to work for me.

Comment: Clearing the IE cache didnt help me but actually Logging in with the internet explorer as the TFS user into tfs servers web and then signing out worked...tried the answers but none worked for me until i tried this. also cleared `IdentityService` folder from `LocalAppData` but it didnt help untill i relogged using IE itself...

Comment: I ran into this problem, too. However it was because my password had expired and I didn't know it until I restarted the computer.

Comment: this works:http://www.niranjankala.in/post/How-to-fix-error-TFS-connection-error-You-are-not-authorized-to-access-%E2%80%A6

Comment: Try this link https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-tf30063-error-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-team-foundation-serv/. Somebody said Step 4 worked for him and i tried that. It worked like a charm. There are other methods in this link to fix this issue.

Comment: In VS2022, go to Help / Register Visual Studio.
Under All Accounts it'll list the accounts you are using.
If present, click Re-enter your credentials.

Answer (score 197, accepted):

I solved this issue by using the browser from within Visual Studio, View->Other Windows->Web Browser; `Ctrl+Alt+R` (or * `Ctrl+W, W`* in VS versions before VS2010) to navigate to the TFS page and log out of the wrong account and log back in.

For me, the issue was caused by using another live-id to unlock a windows phone for development. Somehow the credentials got cached, it seems.

Comment: This is the best and fastest way.

Comment: Awesome - I am using Windows 8 and signing into Windows with my LiveId.  This trick allowed me to "trick" Visual Studio into using a different LiveId.  Very nice.

Comment: How, oh how, did you discover this?

Comment: @Holf It's a long time ago, but I think I've read about browser issues and remebered that there's a builtin browser :)

Comment: After I try your method, it goes to live.com ( I can see that in URL only ) and the page remains blank.  Sometimes it tells "loading identity provider" . Still whole web page is blank. I have tried clearing Internet option->delete . I selected all boxes to clear it. However that was my desktop IE browser. Can we find these options in the inside browser as well? Don't the two browsers have same cache?

Comment: @qqqqq I don't think the have the same cache, otherwise the issue wouldn't even exist.

Comment: how to navigate TFS page please help I cound not follow up your explanation

Comment: @clarifier Where did you get stuck?

Comment: I Followed The Process as Suggested Above View->Other Windows->Web Browser; but got stuck after that I could not find How to navigate to TFS from That point Thanks in Advance

Comment: @clarifier In the tab that opens, navigate to the respective TFS (either visualstudio online or your local TFS installation). Enter the URL below the tab header.

Comment: Anyways all Those were Fine I Have Found The solution and Now it is working fine

Comment: that didn't work for me.  I brought up the "Team Explorer" tab, clicked on the "Select Team Project" and it let me enter my new password.

Comment: I used the browser in VS and logged in to TFS Online. I then opened the project I was having problems in and everything worked ok.

Comment: When I open the VS Web Browser and navigate to the TFS site, I get and error 401.  I've tried clearing authentication, adding new authentication manually.  Clearing IE cookies.  Nothing works.  The VS Web Browser still says error 401.  I can even login to the same url in IE and it works fine.

Comment: Clicking [Sign out and connect with another login] didn't work for me. Further down on the page, I clicked the "You can get a list of your accounts *here*" and this allowed me to switch to the correct account

Comment: For me the issue wasn't that I had wrong credentials, it was that I was pointing to the wrong base URL of the project. (How it did this I have no clue). What fixed it for me was, `Team Explorer > Manage Connections (Little Plug next to Home button) > Right Clicked on Project > Connect.` Then it allowed me to reenter in my credentials. Then worked! **EDIT:** Just realized that is @Rizowski 's answer in the answers.

Comment: I get the following message: 'Navigation to the webpage was cancelled'

Comment: I had to log in using the same username but a personal account. Make sure to try both the work/professional account and the personal account.

Comment: 7 Years later and it's still and issue (when using multiple Live-IDs on the same PC) and this worked for me once I'd restartedVS 2017. Thanks

Comment: This did not fix it for me :(

Comment: When I click on the 'View->Other Windows->Web Browser' it says that TeamCity has dropped support for Internet Explorer.  I have also spent time searching, but cannot see how to change the default browser for Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Found the issue was resolved when I changed VS `Options->Environment->Web Browser` to `External Editor` and picked edge using `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe`  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243177/change-default-web-browser-in-visual-studio

Answer (score 280):

When I came accross this issue none of the provided answers solved this problem or if it did I didn't like recreating the project. The way I ended up solving the issue:

[image]

1. Clicking on the "Connect to Team Projects button" (The plug next to the home button in the Team Explorer tab)
2. Right click the project you are getting this issue on.
3. Click Connect.

I guess the "Remember me" cookie timed out but gave me a generic response for trying to push or pull any code.

Comment: Yeah, the pathway to acceptance on this option appears hazardous with the various warnings especially when you have modified code waiting to checkin. But it seems like it has been designed to deal with the TF30063 situation. None of the other suggestions worked for me.

Comment: This just happened to me in an office where *everything* was turned off and unplugged overnight due to 100+ mph gales. I'm assuming that once the TFS server restarted it needed anyone to re-authenticate...

Comment: This was it.  I figured it out.  Didn't read down far enough to find your answer, so I figured it out myself.  But this is really the correct answer

Comment: Thank you for this solution! I was starting to pull my hair out over this!

Comment: Thank you, this solution worked perfectly.  Tried the top suggestion, but didn't work for me, this one did.

Comment: I had to change my Windows password before this solution would work. The password wasn't expired, but was expiring soon.

Comment: The other reason could be possibly in my case - because of corporate password change policy VS might have been caching my older password which I must have changed several times in last few quarters whenever I get that reset password prompt from windows. For all check-in and checkouts I was using gitBash console which has its own cache of credentials. This prompt was really frustrating and causing unnecessary delay in loading my solutions. Thank you for your post!

Comment: Unbelievable that MS does not make this easier

Comment: FYI: as of September 2017, the steps described by Rizowski are still necessary, even when using the latest, and supposedly greatest, Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise (15.3.3) on Windows 10 64-bit (Version 1703, OS Biuld 15063.540).  

What's old is new, I suppose.

Comment: This has worked in the past for me but didn't work today (why does this keep happening??).  Tried @S.Hoseinpoor's solution below (which in my mind should do the same thing) but that worked.

Comment: This is THE solution!

Comment: Here is one more trick in case the right click was not enough https://stackoverflow.com/a/73478199/2616377

Answer (score 72):

For me the error came after changing my password for my AD account.

I had to remove the line from **credential manager** (which contained the previous password.)

Then it worked again.

Comment: Ridiculous.  Yup, that fixed it for me aswell.  I had the same issue - I had to change my AD password yesterday, and then, TFS refused to connect.  Even worse, I couldn't even quit VS2013, as it blocked me, due to TFS wanting to connect first... but it wasn't able to.  Changing my password in Credential Manager solved it for me aswell.  Many thanks !

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me. The other answers did nothing.

Comment: This fixed me up, on Windows 10.

Comment: This is the only thing that has worked for me! Not sure why VS isn't prompting for authorization when it gets an access denied error.

Comment: Only thing that worked for me also, after updating my network password.

Comment: Works perfectly for me! I had this problem after changing  AD password.

Comment: This worked for me too, but I had to open TFS in IE (v9 or later) and then log in there. Only once I logged into TFS via IE did visual studio stop throwing its toys around. (WIn10 64bit, VS2017 (v15.5.3), IE v11.523)

Comment: Seems to work first then I got could not read Password for 'https://xxx@dev.azure.com': terminal prompts disabled

Comment: This answer fixed my issue for Windows 10 1909 (18363.1440), Visual Studio 2019 (16.4.5) and Azure DevOps Server 2019 (17.143.28621.4)

Comment: This fixed it for me! All other items above did not.

Comment: I had to log-in again and it worked. I've changed my password due to company's security measurements.

Comment: I had to go nuclear on the credentials manager and log out of Office because just the Office related line wasn't enough. I also logged out of DevOps and OneDrive for good measure, restarted the PC again and now it's back working

Comment: Removed credential, restarted VS, no issues. Started after renewing SSO certificate, have had to do this before.

Answer (score 37):

I have upgraded TFS 2015 to TFS 2017, and then the TF30063 error occured on one of my client machines. None of the solutions here worked...

For me the only solution that worked was running the following command from the [Developer Command Prompt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/developer-command-prompt-for-vs):

```
tf workspaces /collection:https://tfs.xxxxx.com/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Of course, you need to adjust the url to the valid one.

Source: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/tfs/admin/backup/refresh-data-caches

Comment: This error was driving me nuts, this solved my problem, thank you soo much.

Comment: Worked for me in VS2017 Enterprise

Comment: Worked also for VS2017 Pro with Win 10 Pro

Comment: This worked, but I had to close VS, then run the command, then reopen, if you just ran it while VS was running it didn't seem to have any effect...

Comment: Works for VS2017 Enterprise. kudos to you.

Comment: Worked for VS2017 Pro.

Comment: You may have to 1) Close VS 2) Remove credentials from CredentialsManager 3) Run tf workspaces command 4) Open VS & TeamExplorer and you will be prompted for credentials again. This address the problem in my case.

Comment: It worked for me too. In my case command needed a different URL format: tf workspaces /collection:https://yourcompanyname.visualstudio.com/ .

Comment: Worked for me in VS2022

Comment: "tf permission" also works - but you have to close & reopen visual studio

Answer (score 30):

The TFS Preview login apparently uses Internet Explorer and thus might conflict with other MS Accounts you are using. Fully clearing the IE cache seems to work for me. After the cache clearing, I get to the correct login screen and may enter my credentials as needed.

Comment: In Windows 10 clearing the Cache of Edge browser will NOT work.  You must clear it in IE.  FYI.

Comment: This also work in vs2017 community where I've setup my vs with both on premise tfs and visualstudio.com account.

Comment: this worked in VS 2017 after I reset my user's password via computer management. Had to restart Visual Studio after that. Opening the web view in Visual Studio (`ctrl`+`alt`+`r`) and trying to open the TFS page only gave me an error about invalid login information but no way to log out.

Comment: I got this error when trying it from a server that didn't have Internet Explorer installed.  Switching to a server that *did* have it installed fixed it for me.

Comment: As odd as it looks (since I never entered my credentials on IE), this worked,

Answer (score 22):

I tried all of the suggestions here. None worked. This could be my particular situation where I connect some VS instances to our company TFS and some instances to my private TFS.

The only way to solve it for me is to close all VS instances and start a new instance.

Oddly enough, connecting to the internal TFS is never a problem. Connecting to ***.visualstudio.com sometimes raises this issue.

Comment: Came here to agree that after trying all the above answers, this is the only one that worked for me.  I am using a similar setup as you where I am connecting with my company name to my personal TFS.

Comment: Restarting VS fixed it here too.  I did happen to name my project after my company but I'm not sure how TFS would know that name from any other name...?

Comment: So odd! This is how I fixed my problem with VS2017.

Answer (score 12):

In VS 2015 it can be achieved by
Team Explorer > Connect > Manage Connections
and selecting the team project again. In case of there exist more than one account in VS, Team Explorer asks for which account to use to connect to the team project.

Answer (score 10):

I tried the following to resolve this issue. Hopefully one of these will work for you

A - Close VS then start the VS Developer Command prompt as an administrator. Then enter: `devenv /resetuserdata`

B - Clear the cache in IE (apparently VS uses this to access your account [mentioned here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/adbb8bcf-16cc-4476-8154-3b5358543d02/tfs-service-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-projectnamedefaultcollection?forum=TFService))

C - Click `View -> Other Window -> Web browser (CTRL+ALT+r)` sign in to your old account, log out and sign in to your new one

D - Open the folder containing you solution, delete (backup if you want) the `Visual Studio Source Control Solution Metadata File` delete the `.suo` file and open the .sln file in Notepad and delete the below section

```
GlobalSection(TeamFoundationVersionControl) = preSolution
    SccNumberOfProjects = 6
    SccEnterpriseProvider = {**********************}
    SccTeamFoundationServer = theServer
    SccLocalPath0 = .
    SccProjectUniqueName1 = pro
    SccProjectName1 = myProject.BL
    SccLocalPath1 = myProject.BL
    .....more stuff.....
EndGlobalSection
```

The last step was required because, while I had managed to disconnect VS my solution was still trying to connect to the old source control account.

Comment: At my company, we use our Windows credentials to log into TFS. When I changed my Windows password, I couldn't log into TFS anymore through VS2017. Step A and B of this answer solved my issue.

Comment: Awesome, 'A' was all I needed as well

Comment: The first step resolved my issue in VS 2017 Community edition. Thanks a lot

Comment: Just step A of your solution fixed it for me.

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that Windows Authentication hasn't been disabled for the Website / Application within IIS.

I'm not sure HOW this happened, but I did uninstall Hyper-V today to be able to install VMWare Player and then re-install Hyper-V

Reenabling this allowed everything to work again.

[image]

Comment: Where is this, exactly? TFS? Windows? I don't know what I'm looking at.

Comment: that is `IIS` in the `Authentication` section

Comment: You are a Life saver!

Answer (score 8):

In team explorer I removed project... then in Manage Connections, clicked on 'Connect to a Project...'

[image]

[image]

In this screen choose your project then click on Connect... this solved my problem.

Comment: Thank you, this worked for me too - tried the top 5 suggestions and none of them worked this time (other methods worked in the past, this keeps happening to me!). Didn't need to remove the project, I was just able to reconnect.  Just added an extra screenshot.

Comment: Thank you - this worked for me in VS2022. It seems that the VS itself thought I was connected to Devops until it came time to perform an action whereby my account was rejected due to being unauthorised. My guess would be that the cookie was expired. Performing the action described in your answer fixes the problem, I would guess, by refreshing the cookie.

Answer (score 6):

This happens to me regularly, and none of the solutions described above works every time.
Most of the times the solution where you use the "Connect to Team Projects button" works fine, but sometimes nothing happens when I do this.

Other times I simply have to re-login to http://tfs.visualstudio.com using the Visual Studio built-in browser (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>) or via Internet Explorer.

(As suggested in some of the other answers, for my part this is not caused by multiple live-ids)

Comment: I normally can use Rizowski's answer but this one worked for me in the recent case of signing in with the wrong Microsoft Account.  This was a lot less painful than clearing everything in IE.

Comment: The site http://tfs.visualstudio.com/ does not exist. Please edit your answer. I'm stuck with this problem, which seems to happen randomly.

Answer (score 5):

None of the current answers worked for me. I found a solution [here](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/93366/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-visualstu.html).

> The issue was that my previous credentials were cached by the Windows
>   OS for the TFS server. While some people might have had success wiping
>   out the AppData temp folders, that is not required.
>
> You need to update the credentials through Control Panel on the
>   Windows OS.
>
> For me on Windows 10: Close VS. Go to Control Panel (with small icon
>   view)-->User Accounts-->Manage your credentials (on the left
>   column)-->Select "Windows Credentials"-->Scroll down to the "Generic
>   Credentials" section and look for your TFS server connection. Expand
>   the pull down and click "Edit". Enter in new network password. Reopen
>   VS and everything should work again.

Comment: This solved my issue, windows had cached my credentials and I had to update my password on my domain and the OS wasn't smart enough to do the same for the cache.

Comment: This solved my problem (from the linked article):
Close all instances of VS
Delete %localappdata%.IdentityService
Restart VS

Answer (score 5):

Just restarting the visual Studio would do the job. As I did this and it worked like a charm

Answer (score 4):

I have just removed the server from Team Explorer, then added again, and it worked =).

Comment: This should work fine with regular TFS server. However this won't work with the TFS preview. After re-adding the server, you still get the IE-based login process. If you have another liveid than the one authorized logged in, you won't get prompted for username/password (see my anwser below)

Answer (score 4):

When Visual Studio prompted me for Visual Studio Team Services credentials there are two options:

1. Use a "Work or School"
2. Use a "Personal" account

In my situation I was using a work email address, however, I had to **select "Personal"** in order to get connected.  Selecting "Work or School" gave me the "tf30063 you are not authorized to access..." error.

For some reason my email address appears to be registered as "personal" even though everything is setup in Office 365 / Azure as a company.  I believe the Microsoft account was created prior to our Silver Partnership status with Microsoft.

Answer (score 4):

Disconnect from Team Fountation Server under Team Menu and reconnect it from Connect Tab under Team Explorer Window

[image]
[image]

Comment: This worked!  Nothing else worked for me - thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

I got this error, after all fiddling work I could do — the disk space was full!

Clearing it fixed my issue.

Answer (score 3):

I've experienced this issue after an TFS upgrade, and somehow Visual Studio is caching invalid login credentials. I've found two ways to fix it, first, [using this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27728464/2912011) I completely reset Visual Studio, then reconnected:

> Click on menu *Tools* → *Import and Export Settings* → *Reset all settings* → *Next* → *"No, just reset settings, overwriting all current settings"* → *Next* → *Finish*.

For some strange reason, after the reset it connected without issue (I didn't even have to re-enter my credentials or reconfigure TFS after the reset).

The second approach was easier. First close all instances of Internet Explorer and Visual Studio, then open Internet Explorer and browse to TFS, login, then open Visual Studio again and attempt to connect to TFS one more time.

Answer (score 3):

I finally found the right answer for me on the web.

For me it happened after I changed my password and Windows cached the TFS password. It is require to be updated manually. This is one way to do it:

Solution found at: [developercommunity.visualstudio.com](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/151627/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-after-pas.html)

CREDIT: Lavente Nagy! Thanks so much!

Fix Summary:

> I found a solution, and it works on Windows 7/Windows 10 too. The steps are the same:
>
> Close Visual Studio. Go to Control Panel (with small icon view) → User
>   Accounts → Manage your credentials (on the left column) → Select
>   "Windows Credentials" → Scroll down to the "Generic Credentials"
>   section and look for your TFS server connection. Expand the pull down
>   and click "Edit". Enter in new network password. Reopen Visual Studio and
>   everything should work again.

Answer (score 3):

I was also facing the same issue as you did. Here is what I did to solve:

**METHOD 1**

1. Click the 'Connect' icon just next to Home icon in Solution Explorer.
2. Choose your project > Right Click > Connect.
3. Try Check-in the project and this time it will happily proceed.

This is what I tried, and I did not need to logout from any sessions from TFS or VS Account.

**METHOD 2**

1. Just press refresh on the top of Team Explorer.
2. Try to Check-in.

This is also easy method.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

I had to "run as a different user" to get Visual Studio to connect using my TFS account. It seemed to be trying to use my Microsoft account instead.

Text and image from: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/connect/connect-team-projects

To change accounts

To run Visual Studio under an account that is different from your logged on Windows account, open the context menu for devenv.exe to access your run as options.

[image: Context menu for Visual Studio devenv.exe]

You can locate the executable in the following folder: Drive:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE.

Answer (score 2):

**Check the information in registry :** 
*HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\VSCommon\Keychain\Accounts*  and delete the related keys under Accounts section.

**Clear the cache in these paths:**

- %localappdata%\Microsoft\TeamTest
- %localappdata%\Microsoft\Team Foundation
- %localappdata%\Microsoft\VisualStudio
- %appdata%\Roaming\Microsoft\VisualStudio

Hope this will work.

**Note: By doing this may clear all the cookies and caches and load the Visual Studio New.**

Answer (score 2):

What isn't officially an answer here, but worked for me (the other answers didn't help):
Click Team Explorer tab -> Connect hyperlink - connect\choose repository.  And it works.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your password hasn't coincidentally expired exactly on the same day you decided to install a new dev machine.

If you can't even log into TFS using the web interface then this may be the case.

Answer (score 1):

Now I got the solution to the problem which I have faced:
The TFS remembered the prior password when I got logged in by using my mobile VPN.

Solution:

Resetting the account that I used to connect using VPN

Comment: This would not have been an issue with only TFS. It would have been an issue with everything connected to your NT Login.

Answer (score 1):

I get this problem when I am forced by our IT security policy to change my password. After a password change, when I connect to TFS using VS2017, I am no longer authorized to access our TFS server and get the `TF30063: You are not authorised to access ...:8080/tfs` error message.

However, if I connect using VS2013, I can connect to the server without problems **and** the access denied error with VS2017 goes away.

Answer (score 1):

It would be a lot easier if the error message were to tell us the username it's trying to access TFS with.

I've been coping with this for a while, and usually logging back in only for the next day to stop again.

I found I had two accounts and removing the unwanted one fixed the issue.

[image]

This is under `Help > Register Visual Studio`

Comment: Had this happen again today when I got a new laptop. The new laptop forced me to change my password, then on the previous laptop I got all kinds of errors. No amount of refreshing or trying to log-in would get it back until I clicked 'Remove' and re-added it again.

Answer (score 1):

Go to "Menu > Disconnect from Server". Then open Team Explorer, double click on the project to connect again solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try making Internet Explorer your default browser temporarily.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had a proxy. I had edited the devenv.exe.config and set the proxy there. But today I changed the proxy domain password and TFS failed (menu *View* → *Windows* → *Browser* also failed). I could of course have edited the devenv.exe again. But there was a solution to remove it altogether. A brilliant one. It is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13717815/visual-studio-error-407-proxy-authentication-required#13769953).

Open menu TOOLS* → *Extensions & Updates*. 
Click on Updates... in the left-hand menu

Here it asks for password and restarting Visual Studio. All okay. For more info, look for the answer in the link.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Just enter a new Credential]

1. press Win button, then type credential manager and open it .
2. Add generic credentials.
3. Go back to team explorer, add the server again.

Answer (score 0):

I went through a number of these solutions too, here what worked for me:

For some reason Team explorer thought I was trying to upload to a new project.

Under Team Explorer -> Sync

I clicked "Advanced" which then showed a Project dropdown as well, which I didn't have to change in my case, I just clicked Publish Repository, and voila.

Answer (score 0):

After updating from TFS 2018 v3 to DevOps Server 2019.0.1 last weekend I now receive this authentication error when attempting to manage security:

TF30063: You are not authorized to access tfs.

I receive this error when attempting to manage security from the Server Administration Console via Application Tier > Administer Security. I also receive the error when I attempt to set permissions via tfssecurity cli tool. I am in the local administrator group and I am listed in the console administration user section.

I'm trying to set permissions because after the update I received several reports from employees that receive errors when they try to access their projects. Those errors are:

TF40049: You do not have licensing rights to access this feature: Code.

I spent 8 hrs working through this issue yesterday, and this is what fixed our problem:

- deleted DevOps server cache. (location of cache listed in devops admin console on server)
- reboot server.

I deleted the cache off the server based on an article I read with the same error, a user was having security/permissions issues with visual studio and they deleted the vs cache on their local machine and it solved their problem. I don't know if deleting the cache or the reboot would have fixed it independently because I did them both as a single troubleshooting step.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, all the above didn't work (worked partially though)!

In **credential manager**, under **Windows credentials** and **Generic Credentials** both places I had to add user credential.

In Windows Credentials,
TFS Server name without "http" and port info. Just server name.

In Generic Credentials,
TFS Server name with "http" and port info. like, http://servername:8080/

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If Rizowski's answer of clicking the green plug connect-button doesn't work *and* you have multiple workspaces, the problem might go away by switching to the other workspace and back again.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem not resolved after trying all the above solution for me, then the below command resolve the issue. open a run command on windows and just copy the below command and make the necessary changes like domain\loginname and the VS path

runas /netonly /user:domain\loginname "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"

Answer (score 0):

The littel "Manage Connection" button was mentioned here before. Hower right click and connect did not solve the issue for me.

[image]

Clicking on "Manage Connections"  > "Connect to a Project" allowed me to enter my credentials again and finally reestablished the connection.