# TFS locks up when trying to pull down an .exe file

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, tfs

When trying to pull down an exe file from TFS, it breaks with the not supported error below, then it prompts for login credentials 4 times, and prompts with the unauthorized error below. After that, I can no longer access anything in TFS until I restart visual studio.

[image: Error MSG 1]
[image: Error MSG 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sort of server setting that needs to be updated on TFS to allow exes.

According to the error TF30063, this may caused by your authentication account of tfs.

Try below steps:

1. Clicking on the "Connect to Team Projects button" (The plug next to
   the home button in the Team Explorer tab)
2. Right click the project you are getting this issue on.
3. Click Connect.

More ways to solve this issue for your reference:[Error TF30063: You are not authorized to access ... \DefaultCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection)

If you can pull down other files from another project without any error. Please also double check the permissions. Make sure you have enough permissions. More details you can check this blog: http://nkdagility.com/tfs-2012-issue-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-and-cant-trace-permissions/