# TFS Related: Why is it required to login to VPN even when I am logged into to office network

Tags: tfs, vpn

On getting latest for a branch from TFS, I got an error

> "TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/8.5."

only for a particular file in a folder of one of the projects. Searching for solution online I came across [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection) which suggested to log out of some wrong account and log back in.

However I have only one account which is my office domain account and I cannot use any other account to login to TFS. On checking with some colleagues they just asked me to login to VPN and try. I basically use VPN to connect to office network when I am working from home. Though I was already in office I was suggested to login to office network and try to get the latest for that file which worked.

My query is when I was not connected to VPN and while getting latest from TFS, why the error

> "TF30063: You are not authorized to access Microsoft-IIS/8.5."

not occur on other files in that same folder whereas it occurred for only one file and how come logging to to VPN resolved it?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Can you check and share the logs in Event Viewer of the TFS server? Did you get the same log as this issue: https://mattyrowan.com/2014/02/26/tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-microsoft-iis7-5/?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be a cache issue. First,try to **remove** your office account info which stored in **Credential Manager** （*Control Panel-All Control Panel Items-Credential Manager-Windows Manager*）

[image]

Also [clear TFS and VS cache](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/willy-peter_schaub/2010/09/15/if-you-have-problems-with-tfs-or-visual-studio-flush-the-user-cache-or-not/). Then reconnect  to TFS in Visual Studio and do the get latest for that particular file.

---

**Update**

1. Checkout that particular file and check in an old version of that
   file.
2. Do the "take latest" action.

This may not generate the error again.

Comment: Thanks Patrick for that information, but I do not have any credentials stored in Credentials stored in Credential Manager, Clearing the TFS cache did not work either.

Comment: After clear cache, on  TFS Server machine, click *Start* and select *Run*…  open the dialog box, then input ***iisreset.exe*** and click OK, wait it run completely. You can also try the method in my update answer, this operation may not generate the error again.