# TFS changedset's author name is not the one who created it

Tags: tfs

I'm starting to study TFS version control. I have added one member in my project and that member just checked-in newly created class and edited some code. My question is why his name does not reflect on the change-set? It is always my name  displayed for all the changesets even if the member is actually the one who created/checked-in the code.

Please see below image

[image]

Kiko Coder is not the one who checked-in those changedsets but my team member.

Below is the screenshot of my team member when he logged in to his account
[image]

When he open the project in ocisnarf89.visualstudio.com(Member), after he checkedin the code/new file it doesn't reflect his name but the name Kiko Coder which is me.

Comment: Are they logged into Visual Studio using your active directory account?

Comment: active directory? I don't think so, because my  team member has his own outlook/microsoft account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I'd like to thank all who gave me an idea.
For my question above, I found out that the VS cached the microsoft account that I used and even if I opened the project from the web portal using the team member acount and successfully opened the project but still the account connected in TFS (from VS) is the owner (previously signed-in account) and not the team member account.

To resolve this, sign-in in VS, then on Team Explorer tab, click Connect | NameOfMyProject then click Project and My Terms then click Connect to Team Projects there will be a pop-up window where you will select the project to connect to, on the lower left corner click "Switch User" and that's it!

I am now able to see the team member name reflected on changed sets.

Please see image below
[image]

Comment: Glad you have figured out the issue and thanks for the sharing.

Answer (score 2):

It's most likely your team member connected to TFS using your account. If so, then any operation is recorded with your ID info.

Please double check no matter the web portal and VS. Make sure they are using their own account. You could find the account info in **Windows-Control Panel- Credential Manager**. How to delete the stored account and related cache, please refer this question [TFS Related: Why is it required to login to VPN even when I am logged into to office network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40429900/tfs-related-why-is-it-required-to-login-to-vpn-even-when-i-am-logged-into-to-of)

---

**Update:**

For TFS you can't swith user directly.

[image]

Comment: Hi, my team member logged in using his outlook/microsoft account,

Comment: @Francis Did you check the VS account , there be some cache with your account and you could delete the related stored info in Windows-Control Panel- Credential Manager.

Comment: Since you had added tag with TFS2013. I misunderstood  that you are using TFS2013. If you  connected to  a TFS server , **You can't switch user in the connect project pag** ( without "swithing user" option) Details you can see my update screenshot.  So you have to delete the cached account info in Credential Manager which will including some info with your tfs sever address such as `http://XXX:8080/tfs` . If you are using VSTS, there shouldn't be any related stuff. You just need to switching user through the way you mentioned as below.