# How to add the view in browser option back into Visual Studio 2017 context menu?

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I've just upgraded to VS 2017 and unless I'm missing something the view in browser option on the right click menu seems to have vanished.

Anyone know how to get it back?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I just installed Visual Studio 2017 and noticed this option was missing from the Project context menu.

However you can right click on project files to view them in the browser.

To add the "View in Browser" option back into the Project context menu, follow these steps:

- Click on Tools > Customize
- Select the "Commands" tab
- Highlight the "Context menu" option
- In the dropdown select "Project and Solution Context Menus | Project"

[image]

- Click "Add Command"
- Select the "File" category
- In the Commands list, select "View in Browser" and press OK

You can then position the option in the menu and the option will be available to use once again.

Comment: Weird, this is a fresh install. When I right click on this project on VS2015 I have a view in browser but it doesn't show in VS2017.

It's not just me, there are 3 other devs in the office where it's not showing for them.

http://i.imgur.com/sXsh0Km.png

Comment: @Alex Here, too. Working with Community Edition of VS 2017, no right-click "View in Browser" menu item in Solution Explorer anymore, _when right-clicking the project node itself_. When right-clicking a .cshtml or an .aspx file, the "View in browser" menu item _is_ present. I've upgraded from VS 2015 Community Edition.

Comment: In visual studio 2017 Enterprise, select "Project and Solution Context Menus | Project | View"

Comment: +1 Project and Solution Context Menus | Project | View is the context sub-menu, most are probably used to and will only show up in a web project. If you place the command in Project and Solution Context Menus | Project, the command will show in any project and be disabled if it is not applicable. (e.g. a Class Project.)

Personally, I think it is better to put it in | Project | View so it only shows when you can use it.

Comment: Unless I'm doing something wrong, in class view I've also noticed that _add field_ is also missing. I can't seem to find it under the add command window. Got any tips?

Comment: above answer is still valid for Visual Studio 2022

Answer (score 1):

Actually (in 15.8.7), it is still in the context Menu - in a sub-menu under View

[image]

Jon L's method will create it in the main menu as well

Alternatively, just use the shortcut - press Ctrl+Shift+W

Answer (score 0):

Concerning the '**View in Browser**' in Visual Studio.

- In the solution explorer, right-clicking on an allowed web document(htm, html, asp, aspx, etc) allows the page to come up in our default browser.
- **Most other files do not provide the 'View in Browser' option**.
- but a right-click on the **solution/project/website name(1st in the list at top**) does provide the 'View in Browser' option, yet it does not find the default document specified in 'Specific Page' in the 'web' section of (its) properties!~ and instead will display a Directory Listing of the web site root.