# How to add the 'view in browser' option back into Visual Studio 2017 *Community* Edition context menu?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

This is very similar to the question here: [How to add the view in browser option back into Visual Studio 2017 context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714590/how-to-add-the-view-in-browser-option-back-into-visual-studio-2017-context-menu)

However, I am using the Community Edition of Visual Studio 2017. I've installed the ASP.NET and .NET core workloads, but if I open up a folder rather than a proper solution, when I right-click a regular .html file there is no option to 'view in browser'.

I've tried following the accepted answer on the above question and it has not fixed the issue. If I create a web application with .cshtml files, then I can right-click and choose 'view in browser'.

Previously, with Visual Studio Community 2015, you could install the basic product without any additional extensions or add-ons, and with a website opened as a folder in the Solution Explorer (I.E. not a VS project or solution) you could right-click an HTML file, choose 'View in browser', and the page would be opened up in the default browser to a localhost URL, running in IISExpress. No special configuration or setup required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, I got it - with VS2017 there is a new option 'open folder'. To be able to 'view in browser' you need to ensure you **don't** use this option, and 'open website' instead, then you can 'view in browser' with regular HTML files.

Comment: I had a similar issue, with the View in Browser option disappearing from the context menu for the root project. If you want to launch the whole project in a browser without debugging, you now have to right-click one of the folders under it. Ctrl+Shift+W will also open the project in a browser.

Answer (score 1):

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714590/how-to-add-the-view-in-browser-option-back-into-visual-studio-2017-context-menu) is a good answer to this question written by [Jon L](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4338516/jon-l). From that:

- Click on **Tools** > **Customize**
- Select the "**Commands**" tab
- Highlight the "**Context menu**" option
- In the dropdown select "**Project and Solution Context Menus | Project**"
- Click "**Add Command**"
- Select the "**File**" category
- In the Commands list, select "**View in Browser**" and press **OK**.