# Visual Studio 2019 not showing 'View in Browser' option

Tags: visual-studio-2019

I'm taking a course in HTML & CSS that requires Visual Studio 2019.  I've written the exact script shown in the video over and over but there is no option to 'View in Browser'. I have no previous experience with JavaScript and very little Visual Basic. I've never used visual studio before.
I've uninstalled and reinstalled VS several times with the same problem.
Please help me!!

One of the examples I'm asked to type:

There is no option to 'View in Browser when right clicking or clicking the File tab.
I tried the solutions offered for VS 2017 but they did not work.
My laptop is a fairly new HP with Windows 10 installed.
Below is what comes up when I right click on the script.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uIwCR.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add the view in browser option back into Visual Studio 2017 context menu?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42714590/how-to-add-the-view-in-browser-option-back-into-visual-studio-2017-context-menu)

Answer (score 0):

If your HTML file is part of a project in Visual Studio, then here is one way to view your file in a browser.

1. Right-click on the project name in the **Solution Explorer** window
2. Select **View** > **View in Browser**

You may need to manually change the URL in your browser to get to your HTML file.