# WebBrowser with Internet Explorer Version too old

Tags: c#, visual-studio, webbrowser-control

How can I change the Web Browser from WebBrowser (panel) of Visual Studio (.Net 4.7.3v or 4.8v)?

I would like to chenge from Internet Explorer to Edge.
I'm trying to do a alternator of windows (pages) to show in TV of my work room. We need be updated about new so-calleds and monitoring another thing in other web sites. So I though to use the WebBrowser to acess that pages (sites) in only one window and not controlling the web browser of my computer. But when I try acess sites like "YouTube" appears a message like "That web browser is too old, you need to download one more current.

Comment: Do you see a "Browse With..." option?

Comment: Check out [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/bc469203-cb4a-4477-a8b3-996121b424e6/webbrowser?forum=vbgeneral) forum post.  The code is in VB, but shows how to change the ie version number.  Not sure about edge

Comment: You can use CefSharp (Chromium). A simple example here https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp.MinimalExample

Comment: Well, General G., it is not working.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243177/change-default-web-browser-in-visual-studio) can help you?

Comment: No. It could not help me.