# I'm trying to change my VS 2022 browser from Internet Explorer to Opera GX

Tags: visual-studio

I'm trying to change it from Internet Explorer to opera GX because whenever I use my web browser and look something up it says that my browser isn't supported and I have no clue how to change it from IE to Opera GX

I tried to look around for anything to maybe hint towards changing it but I couldn't find anything.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42243177/change-default-web-browser-in-visual-studio