# TF30063 error from Visual Studio Team Explorer but connected from the web

Tags: visual-studio, tfs

We are trying to setup TFS for our project installed in a Windows Server. All the collection(s) and projects are already created in TFS but while connecting through Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer we are getting the below error in mapping section:

> TF30063: You are not authorized to access xx.xxx.xxx.xx\ABCDEFGH.

While the same user is able to connect the TFS Collection from IE/Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you ever login the VS Team Explorer with other accounts? Can you connect to the TFS on another client machine?

Anyway, please try below ways to narrow down the issue:

1. Log out of Visual Studio Online from all browsers and VS.
2. Remove the existing credential from **credential manager**(Control panel > Credential manager, which contained the previous password)
3. Clear cache from C:\Users\ [your username]
   \AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation{version}\Cache password.)
4. Run "**devenv /resetuserdata**" to clear your logon for Visual Studio.
   Let it finish, it may take a while.
5. Launch Visual Studio, connect to the TFS project again with your
   account.

You can also reference this similar thread: [Error TF30063: You are not authorized to access ... \DefaultCollection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection)