# TF30063:You are not authorized to access dev.azure.com but I can connect

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

I am using Azure Devops and VS2017 15.9.7. 
I am logged into Devops and can sync.
When I open my project I get a message

```
"TF30063": You are not authorized to access dev.azure.com/myproject
```

I have tried going into credentials manager and deleting all the credentials for the devops organisation.

I have looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection?rq=1) and tried logging out via the browser within VS

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/auth-overview?view=azure-devops

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45540726/tf30063-error-from-visual-studio-team-explorer-but-connected-from-the-web?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score 51, accepted):

> TF30063:You are not authorized to access dev.azure.com but I can connect

I have encountered the same issue. (I need to switch back and forth between work account and test account). Of course, there could be so many reasons and it could be different for each (cached another account, or modified the password).

To resolve this issue I have two methods/steps.

---

Step 1 is to clear the credential from credential manager:

Go to Control Panel (with small icon view)-->`User Accounts`-->`Manage your credentials` (on the left column)-->Select `Windows Credentials`-->Scroll down to the `Generic Credentials` section and look for your TFS server connection.

---

Step 2 is to click on the operation that *Connects to the Team Projects* which is the button/plug icon in the `Team Explorer` tab. Then to also right click the project you are getting this issue on and select `Connect`:

[image]

I also have tried other methods but not work for me, if possible, you can check if it is useful to you:

[How To Fix TF30063 Error](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-tf30063-error-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-team-foundation-serv/)

[Error TF30063: You are not authorized to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection?answertab=votes#tab-top)

Comment: What do you mean by "And the method of clicking on the "Connect to Team Projects button" in the Team Explorer tab, then right click the project you are getting this issue on and select connect."  I can't see such a button in Team Explorer.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, Updated with screenshot, hope it to be more clearer.

Comment: thanks, I exited everything I could see in credentials manager and re-connected like you show, but the problem persists.

Comment: I am using Azure Devops not TFS Server

Comment: The problem was that I was opening the project using the Recent Project section of the start page. I closed VS, re-opened and then opened the project via "connect: in Team Explorer. Then exited.  Now it seems to open ok either way.

Comment: @KirstenGreed, Great! Thanks for sharing the info here. And it could help other community members who get the same issues

Comment: By doing the removal of the old credentials on the box I was working on, allowed me to connect to the azure devops project. Thank you for this answer.

Comment: I found removing my TFS connection, then re-adding it worked a treat...
I have no issue with our git projects however... only TFS

Comment: Works also for VS2022.. sign out of VS, then sign in and when done just connect to a project as @LeoLiu-MSFT mentioned in step 2.. cheers

Comment: Was tearing my hair out. My issue that I wasn't able to pull from a private NuGet feed hosted in ADO. Logged and and out of VS, cleared credentials from Credential Manager. In the end I worked out that, if I navigated to the feed url in an incognito window and authenticating using the popup window I could see the feed. This proved that the issue was definitely with VS and that brought me here.

Answer (score 28):

The [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317539/tf30063you-are-not-authorized-to-access-dev-azure-com-but-i-can-connect#comment97419552_55330767) by Kirsten Greed in the accepted solution resolved the issue for me. Reproduced here:

> The problem was that I was opening the project using the Recent Project section of the start page. I closed VS, re-opened and then opened the project via "connect: in Team Explorer. Then exited. Now it seems to open ok either way.

Comment:  This makes absolutely NO sense, logically, ... but 100 percent worked for me! Thanks Microsoft? Why the heck can it not authorize when opening the project directly, vs. just going into VS without a project? ‍♂️ ... well, at least I was able to check in now!

Answer (score 18):

If the is problem like below:

[image: problem screen shot here]

The solution will be like below:

[image: Solution screen shot 1 here]

And after that select:

<kbd>**Re-enter your credentials**</kbd>

Comment: This is the solution with VS2022.

Comment: After a lot of struggle, the solution provided here works for me. Thank you very much. I wish I could give you. more thumbs ups

Answer (score 9):

I had the same issue, It solved by simply rerunning the Visual Studio as Administrator.

Answer (score 9):

Running this command in cmd prompt, forces the re-authentication screen to come up and worked for me:

**tf.exe get . /r**

NOTE: you may need to locate tf.exe on your disk. For instance I have it at this location: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\TF.exe`

Comment: This worked for me after I previously tried unticking all the accounts in the account filter of the Account settings page.

Comment: Esto funcionó para mí en VS 2022. Pero en vez de encontrar el archivo TF.exe en "Program File (x86)" , lo encontré en "Program Files". Ejecuté el comando tf.exe get ./r  sin tener el VS abierto y al abrirlo nuevamente no me pidió las credenciales pero ya estaba conectado.

Comment: Note this will start downloading *every* $thing from AzDO, recursively. Not recommended.

Answer (score 6):

Another reason for this error is that you might have to re-enter your credentials in Visual Studio:

[image]

Restarting Visual Studio and connecting to Azure DevOps did the trick for me.

Answer (score 3):

None of the other methods above worked for me.  I tried this in visual studio 2022 and it worked.

Open the Developer PowerShell (search for PowerShell) and type in the following:

```
TF vc permission
```

This will bring up a login screen and allow you to log in.
After that you should have permission.

Answer (score 2):

Step 1: Add
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer" in the environment variable path

Step 2: remove azuredevops org related credential from credential manager

Step 3: Delete this folder:

C:\Users<UserName>\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache

Step 3:

run tf workspaces /collection:https://dev.azure.com/royalmailgroup in cmd

Answer (score 1):

It might be the case of a password change.
In my case I had update my account password in a different machine. So on machine #02 I went to Visual Studio > Account Settings. After the pop-up opened, there was a message to re-enter credentials.
Sometimes the password isn't updated across all used app/services and you have to enter that manually.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio>Navigate to Tools > Nuget Package Manager >Package Manage Settings>Azure Service Authentication>Verify/Change the account

Answer (score 0):

Leo Liu's answer got me on the right track.  My problem could have originated from having two different Azure DevOps accounts cached in `Windows Credentials` and Visual Studio started choosing which one to authenticate with at random.

1. Log out of both accounts in `Windows Credentials`.
   (The `Manage Connections` window does not have access to source control now.)
2. Open up the Azure DevOps website and logout there.
3. Login on Azure DevOps website.
   (Visual Studio's `Manage Connections` can access source control again.)

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me was open VS without code and connect via Team Explorer, but then also it threw the same error and after some time I logged out of azure web and tried connecting via Team Explorer again and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it is because of the Date and Time of the PC. It works fine after I do the below steps:

1. Close Visual Studio
2. PC Date Time > Untick "Set Time Automatically"
3. PC Date Time > Tick "Set Time Automatically"
4. Open Visual Studio