# F30063: You are not authorized to access issue in Azure Dev

Tags: azure, azure-devops, scheduled-tasks

I have an Windows agent in my server. When i run it as Administrator manually its connecting successfully. But when i added it into Task scheduler to start automatically(restart server) its getting this error

**TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/my-projects**

My windows scheduled task added it to Run with highest privileges. But its getting same issue.

Comment: Is the answer provided by SwethaKandikonda-MT was helpful for you ? if so could you please accept the answer (click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in) as solution for your ask. This could be beneficial to other community members.

Answer (score 1):

### To resolve this issue I have two methods/steps.

Step 1 is to clear the credential from credential manager:

Go to Control Panel (with small icon view)-->`User Accounts`-->`Manage your credentials`  (on the left column)-->Select  `Windows Credentials`-->Scroll down to the  `Generic Credentials`  section and look for your TFS server connection.

---

Step 2 is to click on the operation that  *Connects to the Team Projects*  which is the button/plug icon in the  `Team Explorer`  tab. Then to also right click the project you are getting this issue on and select  `Connect`:

[image]

If possible, you can check if it is useful to you:

[How To Fix TF30063 Error](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/how-to-fix-tf30063-error-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-team-foundation-serv/)

[Error TF30063: You are not authorized to access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection?answertab=votes#tab-top)

For more information you can refer this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317539/tf30063you-are-not-authorized-to-access-dev-azure-com-but-i-can-connect)