# TF.exe and TfSecurity.exe authentication on AzureDevOps

Tags: c#, powershell, authentication, azure-devops

I have a piece of legacy c# code (console application) that runs as a nightly batch and fires off TF.exe and TFSSecurity.exe commands at AzureDevOps.
The commands are built by the c# code and then executed by means of launching PowerShell and executing them.
All have worked fine until now, but lately, it started failing for `tf30063` authentication errors.

`TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/`

As part of my troubleshooting I have picked a few of these commands that are being built and executed them in an interactive PowerShell session.

```
tf permission /recursive $/<tfs_project_name>/ /collection:https://dev.azure.com/<organization_name>/
TFSSecurity /imx adm: /collection:https://dev.azure.com/<organization_name>/
```

It produces the same result - `TF30063: You are not authorized to access https://dev.azure.com/.`

The logged-on user (where the commands are run) is able to access this AzureDevOps URL via a browser.

Digging a bit deeper I ran the command: `tf settings connections help` which returned the following output:

```
Server Url : https://<organization_name>.visualstudio.com/  
User       :
```

I was actually expecting the passed URL here: https://dev.azure.com/
Not sure how this URL got there, or how to get it out - but, be that as it may, the empty user field arouses some suspicion.

I am really trying to figure out what the authentication flow/procedure is when executing these commands (TF and TFSSecurity) in Powershell.
I have been prompted for authentication by an AzureDevOps dialog once, but where do these provided credentials stored? And for how long? 
I have been snooping around the Windows credentials in the Credential Manager, here I  found some bits and pieces - but nothing conclusive.

**Question:**
Does anybody perhaps know how these 2 applications (tf.exe and TfSecurity.exe) handles authentication and storing of credentials?

System specs:
OS: Windows Server 2016
Powershell Version: 5.1.14393.3053
Location (version) of the tf.exe and TfSecurity.exe
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\
Team Explorer>

Comment: Hi @Morné Kruger Did you get a chance to check out below steps. How was it going?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help @Levi, it is much appreciated! I tried your solutions and in the end, no.4 (clearing the cache locations specified) got me some somewhere. I took hold of this opportunity to remove VS2017 and get VS2019 on my machine as well. When running tf.exe the first time after this, I got prompted for credentials immediately and it worked like a charm! For TFSSecurity.exe the experience was less pleasant as it was still complaining about "TF30063: You are not authorized to access". Are you sure that TFSSecurity.exe uses the same cache locations as TF.exe ?

Comment: Hi @Morné Kruger After researching a lot I finally found where the credentials are stored  for Tfssecurity. I updated below answer. Please check it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cached credentials that tf.exe referenced might get corrupted. We donot know what caused this issue, nor can we give a certain method to fix this. You have to try below possible solutions to narrow down the fix.

> 1,

Using the browser from within your Visual Studio, View->Other Windows->Web Browser and navigate to the https://dev.azure.com/. Then check if it is logged in the wrong account, log out and relog in if wrong account is logged in.

> 2,

Running the following command from the Developer Command Prompt for VS:

```
tf workspaces /collection:https://dev.azure.com/<organization_name>
```

> 3,

Go to Team Explorer > Manage Connections (Little Plug next to Home button) > Right Clicked on Project > Connect. Then reenter in your credentials.

> 4, To clear all the caches

Close all Visual Studio instances, delete %LOCALAPPDATA%.IdentityService as you did.

Clear TFS caches %LOCALAPPDATA%\Microsoft\Team Foundation\7.0\Cache

Clear all the browser caches especially for the stored password

> 5, Run Visual Studio as another user:

cd C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\Common7\IDE

runas /netonly /user: devenv.exe

Enter the user possword, then Team Explorer > Manage Connections

If none of the obove method fixes this issue. Please check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47188210/clear-stored-tfs-credentials-in-visual-studio-2017) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12685111/error-tf30063-you-are-not-authorized-to-access-defaultcollection?answertab=votes#tab-top) for more possible solutions.

You can also report a problem to [Micrsoft Develop community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html)(Report a problem > Azure Devops) if above issue persist.

For Server Url : https://.visualstudio.com/. It is the old version [dev.azure.com domain name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/release-notes/2018/sep-10-azure-devops-launch#switch-existing-organizations-to-use-the-new-domain-name-url). The official document says it can be used as usual.

**Update:**

> TF30063 error for TFSSecurity

The cached credentials for TFSSecurity is stored in the registry. You can delete it.

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VSCommon\14.0\ClientServices\TokenStorage\VisualStudio\VssApp
```

After you deleted the cached credentials in above registry. It will prompt you to re-enter the credential when you run tfssecurity.exe command again.

[image]

Comment: Bingo! That was exactly what I was looking for, and solved the problem. After I deleted the registry key in question and ran TFSSecurity.exe again, I was prompted for authentication again. Thanks so much, Levi - you are the best!